# What is the image of the open ball $b(p,r)$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Consider the function $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R^2}$ defined as $f(x,y)=(x^2-y^2,2xy)$ then the image of teh ball $B(P,\frac{1}{2})$, where $P=(0,1)$ is the centre and the radius is $\frac{1}{2}$ is,

A. a closed set

B. A open set

C. neither open nor closed set

D An unbounded set

I computed what this $B(p,\frac{1}{2})$ is, which is the interior of circle $(x-1)^2+y^2=\frac{1}{4}$.But how to obtain its image under the given $f(x,y)$.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Do you know the inverse function theorem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems we can consider $f$ as a map from $\Bbb C$ to $\Bbb C$, which satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

So $f$ is analytic.   In fact everywhere,  so entire. Actually we have $f(z)=z^2.$

Two things:

- by the open mapping theorem,  $f$ is open
- by Liouville $f$ is unbounded

Thus $b)$ appears correct. I don't see how to apply the second part.

Comment: May be I am mistaken, but $f$ is continuous as $\mathbb{R^2}\to \mathbb{R^2}$ and, as closed ball is compact, then $f$ is bounded on closed ball, so, on open ball also. No?

Comment: Yes.  But since $f$ is entire and not constant,  it's unbounded.   It's just an observation.   @zkutch

Comment: Of course $z^2$ is unbounded on $\Bbb C$, but OP is about image of ball.

Comment: I know I just made the observation.   The answer is $b).$  @zkutch

Answer (score 0):

The answer is b.
It cannot be d, since continuous functions send bounded sets into bounded sets (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2522594/prove-that-a-continuous-function-maps-bounded-sets-to-bounded-sets)).

Moreover, $f$ is injective on $y>0$ (where our ball lies). To see this, let's see if $(u,v)=f(x,y)$ has a unique solution there. Since $y>0$ there holds $x=v/(2y)$. From $x^2-y^2=u$ we get $y^4+uy^2-v^2/4=0$. There a unique solution to this quadratic equation in $y^2$, as $y^2>0$. Thus, $f$ is injective in a neighborhood of your ball.

But continuous injective functions are open (this fact is not at all trivial: [see here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Invariance_of_domain)), and so, the image of our open ball is itself open.